# Why Edit data with Vue not work as desired

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, components

I post my code at here 
https://codesandbox.io/s/mm364r6ov8
My problem is , when i click edit , modal show . But , whenever i change data at field name ( or other field ) , data at that row is changed too .
Any suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

That data is changed due to the fact that in your `EditModal` you assign it's `user` property by referencing it to a user object from your users list:

```
self = this;
EventBus.$on("edit-user", use => {
  self.user = use;
});
```

First of all, don't use `self` here because it's redundant if you are using arrow functions.

Now, to make it not edit the user in your users list whenever you edit the input you simply have to make a copy of the user, for example by using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
EventBus.$on("edit-user", user => {
  this.user = Object.assign(this.user, user);
});
```

or a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
this.user = { ...user }
```

Just note that neither `Object.assign` nor destructuring assignment make a deep copy so if you have many nested properties you may want to implement a deep copy function yourself.

I've seen that you probably attempted to make a copy of user before passing it to your modal:

```
editUser(user) {
  var temp = user;
  EventBus.$emit("edit-user", temp);
},
```

However, `var temp = user;` only assigns a `user` reference to `temp`, it doesn't create a new object.

This should fix your problem but your modal's save method doesn't work, but that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

thank for your answer . Finally , i found a way to save data from modal to result row . I must use

```
this.users.splice(8, 1, user)
```

instead of

```
this.users[8] = user;
```

in saveData method .

Of course with

> this.user = { ...user }

of @dziraf